# Antlr Lexer cant recognize Real Number

Tags: antlr, antlr4, grammar

So I have been developing my own compiler from scratch. I have the assembler Completed and I had it working with Integer Numbers. I wanted to add support for Real Numbers that get assembled into binary32 or the standard float format.

**I keep getting errors like the following**

```
line 194:9 mismatched input '8.0' expecting NUMBER
line 200:10 mismatched input '1.0' expecting NUMBER
line 203:10 mismatched input '2.0' expecting NUMBER
line 217:10 mismatched input '5.0' expecting NUMBER
line 221:10 mismatched input '3.1415' expecting NUMBER
line 222:10 mismatched input '12.0' expecting NUMBER
```

My grammar I am using is posted below:

Pay special attention to the REAL_NUMBER and NUMBER lexer rules.
My understanding is that all these numbers should match the longer rule which is REAL_NUMBER but i guess the state machine is just getting stuck inside the NUMBER state and giving me all the above errors.

```
grammar ArmAssembler;

program: instructionOrDirective+;

instructionOrDirective: LABEL? (instruction | 
                                wordDirective | 
                                byteDirective);

instruction: bInstr
       | blInstr
           | bxInstr
       | ldmInstr
       | ldrSignedInstr
       | ldrDefInstr
       | mlaInstr
       | mrsInstr
       | msrDefInstr
       | msrPrivInstr
       | mulInstr
       | stmInstr
       | strSignedInstr
       | strDefInstr
       | swiInstr
       | swpInstr
       | addInstr
       | andInstr
       | eorInstr
       | subInstr
       | rsbInstr
       | adcInstr
       | sbcInstr
       | rscInstr
       | tstInstr
       | teqInstr
       | cmpInstr
       | cmnInstr
       | orrInstr
       | movInstr
       | bicInstr
       | mvnInstr
       | stopInstr
       ;

wordDirective: DOT_WORD number;
byteDirective: DOT_BYTE number;

bInstr : BRANCH expression;
blInstr : BRANCH_WITH_LINK expression;
bxInstr : BRANCH_WITH_EXCHANGE REG;
ldmInstr : LOAD_MEMORY REG EXP? COMMA rList BXOR?;
ldrSignedInstr : LOAD_SIGNED_REGISTER REG COMMA address;
ldrDefInstr : LOAD_REGISTER REG COMMA address;
mlaInstr : MULTIPLY_AND_ACUMULATE REG COMMA REG COMMA REG COMMA REG;
mrsInstr : MRS_INSTR REG COMMA psr;
msrDefInstr : MSR_INSTR psr COMMA REG;
msrPrivInstr : MSR_INSTR (psrf COMMA (REG | poundExpression));
mulInstr : MULTIPLY REG COMMA REG COMMA REG;
stmInstr : STORE_MEMORY REG EXP? COMMA rList BXOR?;
strSignedInstr : STORE_SIGNED_REGISTER REG COMMA address;
strDefInstr : STORE_REGISTER REG COMMA address;
swiInstr : SOFTWARE_INTERRUPT expression;
swpInstr : SWAP REG COMMA REG COMMA LBRACK REG RBRACK;
addInstr : ADDITION REG COMMA REG COMMA op2;
andInstr : LOGICAL_AND REG COMMA REG COMMA op2;
eorInstr : EXCLUSIVE_OR REG COMMA REG COMMA op2;
subInstr : SUBTRACTION REG COMMA REG COMMA op2;
rsbInstr : REVERSE_SUBTRACTION REG COMMA REG COMMA op2;
adcInstr : ADDITION_WITH_CARRY REG COMMA REG COMMA op2;
sbcInstr : SUBTRACTION_WITH_CARRY REG COMMA REG COMMA op2;
rscInstr : REVERSE_SUBTRACTION_WITH_CARRY REG COMMA REG COMMA op2;
orrInstr : LOGICAL_OR_INSTRUCTION REG COMMA REG COMMA op2;
bicInstr : BIT_CLEAR_INSTRUCTION REG COMMA REG COMMA op2;
tstInstr : TEST_BITS REG COMMA op2;
teqInstr : TEST_EQUALITY REG COMMA op2;
cmpInstr : COMPARE REG COMMA op2;
cmnInstr : COMPARE_NEGATIVE REG COMMA op2;
movInstr : MOVE REG COMMA op2;
mvnInstr : MOVE_NEGATIVE REG COMMA op2;
stopInstr: STOP;

op2 : REG (COMMA shift)?
    | poundExpression
    ;

shift : shiftName REG
      | shiftName poundExpression
      | RPX
      ;

rList : LCURL rValue (COMMA rValue)*  RCURL;
rValue : REG (MINUS REG)?;

/*
 * Below is code for dealing with expressions
 */
poundExpression: HASH expression;
expression : andExpr (LOR expression)?;
andExpr : relational (LAND andExpr)?;
relational : primary ((REQ|RNE|RLT|RGT|RLE|RGE) primary)?;
primary : bitwise ((PLUS|MINUS) primary)?;
bitwise : term ((BOR|BAND|BXOR) bitwise)?;
term: unary ((TIMES|DIV|MOD|LSHIFT|RSHIFT) term)?;
unary: (PLUS|MINUS)? single;
single: realNumber
      | number
      | identifier
      ;
identifier: IDENT
          | BRANCH
          | BRANCH_WITH_LINK
          | BRANCH_WITH_EXCHANGE
      | LOAD_MEMORY
      | LOAD_SIGNED_REGISTER
      | LOAD_REGISTER
      | MULTIPLY_AND_ACUMULATE
      | MRS_INSTR
      | MSR_INSTR
      | MULTIPLY
      | STORE_MEMORY
      | STORE_SIGNED_REGISTER
      | STORE_REGISTER
      | SOFTWARE_INTERRUPT
      | SWAP
      | ADDITION
      | LOGICAL_AND
      | EXCLUSIVE_OR
      | SUBTRACTION
      | REVERSE_SUBTRACTION
      | ADDITION
      | ADDITION_WITH_CARRY
      | SUBTRACTION_WITH_CARRY
      | REVERSE_SUBTRACTION_WITH_CARRY
      | LOGICAL_OR_INSTRUCTION
      | BIT_CLEAR_INSTRUCTION
      | TEST_BITS
      | TEST_EQUALITY
      | COMPARE
      | COMPARE_NEGATIVE
      | MOVE
      | MOVE_NEGATIVE
      | STOP
      | shiftName
      | psr
      | psrf
      | REG
      | RPX
      ;

realNumber: REAL_NUMBER;
number: NUMBER;


/*
 * Below is the code for dealing with addresses
 */

address : expression
    | preIndexedAddressing
    | postIndexedAddressing
    ;

preIndexedAddressing: LBRACK REG RBRACK
            | LBRACK REG COMMA poundExpression RBRACK EXP?
            | LBRACK REG COMMA (PLUS | MINUS)? REG 
                      (COMMA shift)? RBRACK EXP?
                    ;

postIndexedAddressing: LBRACK REG RBRACK COMMA poundExpression
                 | LBRACK REG RBRACK COMMA (PLUS | MINUS)? REG
                       (COMMA shift)?
             ;

shiftName: LSL
     | LSR
     | ASR
     | ROR
     ;

psr: CPSR
   | CPSR_ALL
   | SPSR
   | SPSR_ALL
   ;

psrf: CPSR_FLG
    | SPSR_FLG
    ;

/*
 * Below are the shift name variables
 */

ASL : A S L;
LSL : L S L;
LSR : L S R;
ASR : A S R;
ROR : R O R;

RPX : R P X;

/*
 * Below is code for condition codes
 */

BRANCH: B CONDITION_CODE?;
BRANCH_WITH_LINK: BL CONDITION_CODE?;
BRANCH_WITH_EXCHANGE: BX CONDITION_CODE?;
LOAD_MEMORY: LDM CONDITION_CODE? ADDRESSING_MODE;
LOAD_REGISTER: LDR CONDITION_CODE? B? T?;
LOAD_SIGNED_REGISTER: LDR CONDITION_CODE? TRANSFER_TYPE;
MULTIPLY_AND_ACUMULATE: MLA CONDITION_CODE? S?;
MRS_INSTR: MRS CONDITION_CODE?;
MSR_INSTR: MSR CONDITION_CODE?; 
MULTIPLY: MUL CONDITION_CODE? S?;
STORE_MEMORY: STM CONDITION_CODE? ADDRESSING_MODE?;
STORE_REGISTER: STR CONDITION_CODE? B? T?;
STORE_SIGNED_REGISTER: STR CONDITION_CODE? TRANSFER_TYPE;
SOFTWARE_INTERRUPT: SWI CONDITION_CODE?;
SWAP: SWP CONDITION_CODE? B?;
ADDITION: ADD CONDITION_CODE? S?;
LOGICAL_AND: AND CONDITION_CODE? S?;
EXCLUSIVE_OR: EOR CONDITION_CODE? S?;
SUBTRACTION: SUB CONDITION_CODE? S?;
REVERSE_SUBTRACTION: RSB CONDITION_CODE? S?;
ADDITION_WITH_CARRY: ADC CONDITION_CODE? S?;
SUBTRACTION_WITH_CARRY: SBC CONDITION_CODE? S?;
REVERSE_SUBTRACTION_WITH_CARRY: RSC CONDITION_CODE? S?;
LOGICAL_OR_INSTRUCTION: ORR CONDITION_CODE? S?;
BIT_CLEAR_INSTRUCTION: BIC CONDITION_CODE? S?;
TEST_BITS: TST CONDITION_CODE?;
TEST_EQUALITY: TEQ CONDITION_CODE?;
COMPARE: CMP CONDITION_CODE?;
COMPARE_NEGATIVE: CMN CONDITION_CODE?;
MOVE: MOV CONDITION_CODE? S?;
MOVE_NEGATIVE: MVN CONDITION_CODE? S?;
STOP: STP;

REG: R (([1][0-5]?)|[02-9]);
LABEL: IDENT WS* COLON;
IDENT: LETTER LETTER_OR_UNDERSCORE_OR_NUMBER*;

DOT_WORD: '.' WORD;
DOT_BYTE: '.' BYTE;

REAL_NUMBER: [0-9]+ '.' [0-9]+;
NUMBER: [+-]?(([1-9] [0-9]*)|[0]);

CPSR: C P S R;
CPSR_ALL: C P S R '_' A L L;
CPSR_FLG: C P S R '_' F L G;
SPSR: S P S R;
SPSR_ALL: S P S R '_' A L L;
SPSR_FLG: S P S R '_' F L G;    

EXP : '!';

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;

//And here are some operators

COMMA : ',';
LCURL : '{';
RCURL : '}';
LBRACK: '[';
RBRACK: ']';
REQ : '==';
RNE : '!=';
RLE : '<=';
RLT : '<';
RGE : '>=';
RGT : '>';
TIMES : '*';
MINUS : '-';
PLUS : '+';
MOD : '%';
DIV : '/';
LSHIFT : '<<';
RSHIFT : '>>';
BAND : '&';
BOR : '|';
BXOR : '^';
LAND : '&&';
LOR : '||';
HASH : '#';
COLON: ':';

/*
 * The following are used for ldm and store memory instructions 
 */

 /*
 * Below is definitions of all of the tokens to be used
 * B is also declared bit it is declared later at the bottom
 */

fragment STP: S T P;
fragment ADC : A D C;
fragment ADD : A D D;
fragment AND : A N D;
fragment BIC : B I C;
fragment BL  : B L;
fragment BX  : B X;
fragment CMP : C M P;
fragment CMN : C M N;
fragment EOR : E O R;
fragment LDC : L D C;
fragment LDM : L D M;
fragment LDR : L D R;
fragment MCR : M C R;
fragment MLA : M L A;
fragment MOV : M O V;
fragment MRC : M R C;
fragment MRS : M R S;
fragment MSR : M S R;
fragment MUL : M U L;
fragment MVN : M V N;
fragment ORR : O R R;
fragment RSB : R S B;
fragment RSC : R S C;
fragment SBC : S B C;
fragment STC : S T C;
fragment STM : S T M;
fragment STR : S T R;
fragment SUB : S U B;
fragment SWI : S W I;
fragment SWP : S W P;
fragment TEQ : T E Q;  
fragment TST : T S T;
fragment BYTE: B Y T E;
fragment WORD: W O R D;

fragment SB: S B;
fragment SH: S H;

fragment FD: F D;
fragment ED: E D;
fragment FA: F A;
fragment EA: E A;
fragment IA: I A;
fragment IB: I B;
fragment DA: D A;
fragment DB: D B;

fragment TRANSFER_TYPE: H
              | SB
              | SH
              ;

fragment ADDRESSING_MODE: FD
            | ED
            | FA
            | EA
            | IA
            | IB
            | DA
            | DB
            ;

fragment CONDITION_CODE: EQ 
               | NE 
               | CS 
               | CC 
               | MI 
               | PL 
               | VS 
               | VC 
               | HI 
               | LS 
               | GE 
               | LT 
               | GT 
               | LE 
               | AL
               ;

fragment EQ : E Q;
fragment NE : N E;
fragment CS : C S;
fragment CC : C C;
fragment MI : M I;
fragment PL : P L;
fragment VS : V S;
fragment VC : V C;
fragment HI : H I;
fragment LS : L S;
fragment GE : G E;
fragment LT : L T;
fragment GT : G T;
fragment LE : L E;
fragment AL : A L;

fragment LETTER_OR_UNDERSCORE_OR_NUMBER: LETTER | '_' | [0-9];
fragment LETTER: (A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X | Y | Z);

fragment A : ('A'|'a');
fragment B : ('B'|'b');
fragment C : ('C'|'c');
fragment D : ('D'|'d');
fragment E : ('E'|'e');
fragment F : ('F'|'f');
fragment G : ('G'|'g');
fragment H : ('H'|'h');
fragment I : ('I'|'i');
fragment J : ('J'|'j');
fragment K : ('K'|'k');
fragment L : ('L'|'l');
fragment M : ('M'|'m');
fragment N : ('N'|'n');
fragment O : ('O'|'o');
fragment P : ('P'|'p');
fragment Q : ('Q'|'q');
fragment R : ('R'|'r');
fragment S : ('S'|'s');
fragment T : ('T'|'t');
fragment U : ('U'|'u');
fragment V : ('V'|'v');
fragment W : ('W'|'w');
fragment X : ('X'|'x');
fragment Y : ('Y'|'y');
fragment Z : ('Z'|'z');
```

I have tried changing the realNumber parser rule to DIGIT+ DOT DIGIT+ but it will throw a Parser error. Plus I don't want it to match something like 12   .10 (with the spaces included).

So a Lexer rule should be the appropriate solution.

This may just be a bug in Antlr.
I am using Antlr 4.3 as an apache maven plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer... your Lexer rules DO recognize that input as a `REAL_NUMBER` token, but you are in a parser rule that expects a `NUMBER` token; hence, the error.

The error message basically says that the parser was looking for a `NUMBER` token, but, instead found a token with the text of, for example '8.0'. The default error handler does not identify the token type of the input it encountered as it an error intended for the user of your parser, so the literal input is more meaningful to them.  You can override that error handler an spit out a message that DOES name the token type for use while you're developing your compiler.

The sample input you provide in your examples (ex: `3.1415`) will be tokenized as `REAL_NUMBER` tokens (not as `NUMBER` tokens) per the following Lexer rules in your grammar.

```
REAL_NUMBER: [0-9]+ '.' [0-9]+;
NUMBER:      [+-]? (([1-9] [0-9]*) | [0]);
```

The error message would indicate that the parser is looking for a `NUMBER` token, so this would be expected behavior.

BTW... there's a LOT that should probably be reworked, particularly in your approach to Lexer rules, but one parser rules thing I'd point out is that the following rules are not providing any benefit for you. (and may be obfuscating things for you)

```
realNumber: REAL_NUMBER;
number:     NUMBER;
```

It's not really possible from your question, to determine which parser rule is looking for a `NUMBER` where you have a `REAL_NUMBER` (it appears that it would need to be a rule that is looking for a `wordDirective` or a `byteDirective` so best guess is the `instructionOrDirective` rule.  However would really help if you provided your test input as well as the start rule you are using).

Also.. it's ALWAYS a good idea to dump the token stream of your input to ensure that you first understand the stream of tokens being recognized by your Lexer rule and passed to your parser (`grun` with `-tokens` flag is one way to accomplish this (it's also a common capability in ANTLR plugins)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I cant believe I missed that. Ill also be honest this is the first time I have used stack overflow. Thanks for the quick reply.